# What is the best way to aggregate two list of objects?

Tags: java

I have two lists containing student objects. I want to aggregate `objects.status` property in two lists whose studentId are similar.

It is promised that status property in List A is always `null` and status property in List B is not `null`.

```
Student List A:
id:123, name: noname, status: null, address: xxxx, contact: xxx, ....
id:124, name: noname, status: null, address: xxxx, contact: xxx, ....
id:125, name: noname, status: null, address: xxxx, contact: xxx, ....

Student List B:
id:123, name: null, status: accepted, address: null, contact: null, ....
id:124, name: null, status: not-accepted, address: null, contact: null, ....
id:125, name: null, status: accepted, address: null, contact: null, ....


Aggregated list:
id:123, name: noname, status: accepeted, address: xxxx, contact: xxx, ....
id:124, name: noname, status: not-accepted, address: xxxx, contact: xxx, ....
id:125, name: noname, status: accepted, address: xxxx, contact: xxx, ....
```

Normally, I would use two for loops to aggregate both the results. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean to pick which ever is non null? If so, what would be the action required if both lists have non null value for the same property?

Comment: Updated the original question

Comment: will all the other properties of that id be same in both lists?

Answer (score 1):

With streams, You could use a combination of `groupingBy` to group similar ids and the reduce the grouped elements by picking that element with a non-null status:

```java
Stream.concat(a.stream(),b.stream())
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getId, 
                                     Collectors.reducing((x,y) -> (x.getStatus() != null) ? x: y)))
      .values()
      .stream()
      .filter(Optional::isPresent)
      .map(Optional::get)
      .collect(Collectors.toList()); // returns a list of student objects.
```

I am not sure whether this is a "better" way than a traditional `for` loop, but this is one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put one list into the set.

and update the the second  / aggregate list  like below.

```
Map<Long, Student> uniqueStudents = new HashMap<>();
for(Student st : listA)
uniqueStudents.put(st.getId(), st);
for(int i = 0; i < listB.size(); i++)
 {
    Student studentB = listB.get(i);
    Student studentA = uniqueStudents.get(studentB.getId());
    // do aggregation.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
approach : step 1> make a hash map of id->student from list A
           step 2> traverse list B, find out the match from map and
                   make a combined record from list and map of same id,
                   and put that in the output list.

we can assume the existence of the Student class.
*/
List<Student> aggregate(List<Student> A, List<Student> B) {
    Map<String, Student> hm = new HashMap<>();
    for (Student student : A) {
        hm.put(student.getId(), student);
    }
    List<Student> combined = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Student student : B) {
        if (hm.containsKey(student.getId())) {
            Student s1 = new Student(student);//this copy constructor should present in 
                                              //the Student class
            Student s2 = hm.get(student.getId());
            //now combine both of them
            // in this way we are combined all fields which is null in any list
            if (s2.getName() != null) {
                s1.setName(s2.getName());
            }
            if (s2.getStatus() != null) {
                s1.setStatus(s2.getStatus());
            }
            if (s2.getAddress() != null) {
                s1.setAddress(s2.getAddress());
            }
            if (s2.getContact() != null) {
                s1.setContact(s2.getContact());
            }
            combined.add(s1);
        }
    }
    return combined;
}
```