# How to replace custom objects in list based on a condition using Java 8?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Having two lists of custom objects `Entity(id, name) - mainEntityList, otherEntityList` and I want to iterate through them to replace the items in `mainEntityList` with that of `otherEntityList` where the ids match.

Ex

```
mainEntityList = [{1, "abc"},{2, "xyz"}]
otherEntityList = [{2, "value"}]
```

Then after replacing I should have

```
mainEntityList = [{1, "abc"},{2, "value"}]
```

It is working with the conventional loop method but what would be the best solution using java stream? Thanks!

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/66998221/7804477

Answer (score 1):

Create a map from your `otherEntityList` mapping each Id to the Entity object and then use `List.replaceAll` cheking if the map keyset contains the ids in your `mainEntityList`:

```
List<Entity> mainEntityList  = new ArrayList<>();
mainEntityList.add(new Entity(1, "abc"));
mainEntityList.add(new Entity(2, "xyz"));

List<Entity> otherEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
otherEntityList.add(new Entity(2, "value"));

Map<Integer,Entity> map = otherEntityList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getId,Function.identity()));
mainEntityList.replaceAll(entity -> map.keySet().contains(entity.getId()) ? map.get(entity.getId()): entity);
System.out.println(mainEntityList);
```